# Do I need `git checkout` after `git pull`?

Tags: git

After pulling changes committed and pushed by other developers by `git pull`, do I need to run `git checkout` or something else to get my local working copy "fully synchronized" with the latest version of all files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  `git pull` performs both a `git fetch` -- which updates your local *repository* with changes from the remote repository -- and `git merge`, which updates your local *working copy* (the checked out files).

After a `git pull` operation, your working copy should be fully synchronized, barring any local modifications you have made.

Comment: What's the Mercurial equivalent of `git pull`?

Comment: Haven't the foggiest.  Have you tried searching for something like "mercurial for git users"?

Comment: It is very misleading, but it's `hg fetch`... and guess what, `git fetch` is equivalent to `hg pull`! http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts